# SWRevealViewController hierarchy leading to black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

Firstly, I would like to say that there are no errors with my code from a programming standpoint - it runs successfully, so a round of applause for that. However, the issue I am having is that when I run the application, it displays a black screen. I assume the issue has something to do with how I have set up the segues or something similar.

Hierarchy:

Reveal View Controller -> Table View
                                     
-> Navigation Controller -> Tab View Controller -> FirstViewController

**Important To Note:**

- Reveal View Controller class is set to "SWRevealViewController"
- Table View Controller class is not set.
- Table View Controller segue ID set to 'sw_rear'
- Navigation Controller class is not set <**possibly the issue**, but I cannot set the class to SWViewController as suggested by a thread online.>
- Navigation Controller segue ID set to 'sw_front'
- All other controllers have no set class.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the solution. Hopefully others can learn from this.

When you create a project using a Tab Bar Controller as your base, an arrow will appear to the left of the Tab Bar Controller in the Storyboard. Moving that arrow to the Reveal View Controller (View Controller you set to the class of SWRevealViewController) lets Xcode know that you want to start your hierarchy from that object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What helped me resolving the issue was to remove the Navigation Controller that linked to the view (in my case was UItableViewController), and re-insert a new Navigation Controller (clicking the tableviewcontroller, Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller).